# Android Google Map with marker animating Info Box

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android app, and I would like whenever I click on some markers on a Google Map V2, to have an info box animating on the bottom of the page. So practically I want to achieve the same effect as Google Maps. As you can see on the image, if I click on the Tube marker, then a box with additional information opens on the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Does the Google Maps library support something like that? or should I custom implement that and how?

Comment: I don't think so that google maps library supports this.You have to manually add Views to achieve this

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj, are you aware of any tutorial showing how to implement and animate a View like that on top of a map?

Comment: you won't find tutorial for all those features but separated ..

Answer (score 1):

For people who want to achieve something similar, there is a possible duplicate here as a starting point:

[Animation in RelativeLayout to slide down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270665/animation-in-relativelayout-to-slide-down)